# How to connect to two databases via hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

I need to be able to determine which database to use at login time from an application. It's an old code I was asked to help modify based on Struts and hibernate. I need to decide, based on user details, which database to connect to at login time. However I am unsure as to how to proceed with implementing this. I'm new to the both web dev technologies so I'm still learning and according to the book I have I need to create one sessionfactory per dbase. Based on web examples, this sort of problem has been explained in terms of using multi-database within an application but I only need to use the one containing the user details for the duration of the session (details are stored on each database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2.
check this: http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/wiki/3b_Multiple_databases

Comment: Thanks. Although right now I'm abandoning the struts framework for the next development.

Answer (score 0):

You need one connection per database, one EntityManager per database, and code with logic embedded in it to figure out the appropriate circumstances under which each one is used.

Comment: Actually, he will need one EntityManagerFactory per database. There will probably be new EntityManagers for each request.